# Accept a file in a JSON to Java using Jackson

Tags: java, angular, rest, jackson, deserialization

My Angular front end sends a POST request to my SpringBoot backend. Request body contains an object of following Angular interface.

```
export interface Student{

    name: string;
    images: File[];

}
```

I have a Java class in my backend to which the request body should get deserialized into.

```
public class Student implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    private List<java.io.File> images;

    // default constructor

    // geters and setters

}
```

When I send the request, jackson complains the following error indicating that it cannot deserialize the file.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.io.File out of START_OBJECT token

What file type i should use in order to get the request deserialized into a Java object? Or any solution with an annotation for Jackson for this?

Comment: You can use Object mapper for the same

    Map<String, Object> params = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, Student.class);

Comment: This class contains so many other attributes too. In that case how can I handle this using the way you suggest?

Comment: you can explore this link [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)